# Polygon shape margin in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, geolocation, polygon

I have a simple array of geo points. This array represents a non crossing polygon. I have an algorithm that can calculate if a geo point is inside the polygon or not.

This is how my class looks like:

```
public class Polygon
{
   List<LatLng> vertexes;
}
```

However sometimes in order to work the report I need to have a tolerance so I need to make a margin around the original polygon. That means the new polygon must have the same shape but to be bigger by r (value).

Does anyone have an idea how this can be implemented in Java having in mind that my original polygon class has a list of LatLng points.

Comment: Do you really have _regular_  polygons? If so, you could just move all points _r_  away from the centre. (But given that you have latitude/longitude pairs, I doubt that your polygon is regular. Did you mean something else, maybe a convex polygon?)

Comment: 10x for correcting me :)